# Select Products NOT Bought by a Customer

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a test database with just three tables.  How may I select which products have NOT been bought by CUSTOMER ID = 1?
I'm unable to use the NOT IN keywords because in reality each table will be enormous and will exceed the 'IN' limits.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testdata;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdata DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
USE testdata;
SET character_set_client = utf8;


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,     /* Unique Identifier */

  FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,   /* Customer Firstname */
  BALANCE INTEGER DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,       /* Credit balance of customer */

  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

insert into CUSTOMER (FIRSTNAME, BALANCE)
  VALUES ('Steve', 100),
  ('Dwayne', 100),
  ('John', 200),
  ('George', 50),
  ('Alice', 100);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,     /* Unique Identifier */

  ITEMNAME VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,   /* Product name */
  PRICE INTEGER DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,       /* Price of product */

  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ;

insert into PRODUCT (ITEMNAME, PRICE)
  VALUES
  ('Car', 50),
  ('Lego', 12),
  ('Soup', 3),
  ('Paper', 1),
  ('PC', 60);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_PRODUCT (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CUSTOMERID INTEGER NOT NULL,              /* Person ID */
  PRODUCTID INTEGER NOT NULL,               /* Product ID */
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
  ) ;

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_PRODUCT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERS_PROD_PERS FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_PRODUCT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERS_PROD_PROD FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

insert into CUSTOMER_PRODUCT (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID)
  VALUES (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 4),
  (1, 5);
```

I've attempted with something like this and many variations but cannot get 'Soup' and 'Paper' as the result...

```
select * from PRODUCT P
right join CUSTOMER_PRODUCT CP on P.ID = CP.PRODUCTID
left join CUSTOMER C on C.ID = CP.CUSTOMERID
where C.ID = 1 
/* and this is where I get stuck! :( */
```

Comment: You would do a left join product to customer_product and where customer_product returns null

Comment: `select * from product as p where not exists (select 1 from customer_product as cp where cp.customerid=1 and cp.productid=p.id)` or `select * from product as p left join customer_product as cp on p.id=cp.productid and cp.customerid=1) where cp.productid is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to let condition `C.ID = 1` to `ON` from `where` and using `LEFT JOIN`

```
select * from PRODUCT P
left join CUSTOMER_PRODUCT CP on P.ID = CP.PRODUCTID
left join CUSTOMER C on C.ID = CP.CUSTOMERID
AND CP.CUSTOMERID = 1 
WHERE C.ID IS NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b442b98970c001fde61bee7530068a6)

Comment: The query works - it looks a little closer with all products listed but the 'not bought' products are listed with ID null

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: I'm looking for 'Paper' and 'Soup' as the result of what CUSTOMER.ID = 1 has not bought

Comment: @KenAlton Is that your expectation https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b442b98970c001fde61bee7530068a6?

Comment: Yes, that's my expectation.